# Remove object from Collection

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, loops, collections

I have a collection of objects, from which I wish to remove some on the basis of a function call which will return true or false. Please see the sample code snipette below -

```
for each(MyClass obj in Objects)
{
  if(!ValidateObject(obj)
  { Objects.Remove(obj); }
}
```

I don't want to use loop here. Need one liner code for above sample.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You need to be more accurate. 1st - Is `Objects` a collection of `MyClass`? 2nd - What have you tried so far? 3rd - What's the problem? Again, if you don't ask things clearly, it sounds like someone needs to do your homework! ;)

Comment: You might want to explain the reason behind "I don't want to use a loop here". Ultimately every solution will need to loop through all items, removing what's not needed.

Comment: @HansKesting I guess there's no technical reason behind his research, it's just to do it in less lines.

Comment: Yes Matias is very much correct here, I know every solution we may implement will do iteration only. Just wanted to keep my code clean and less cumbersome.

Comment: @Alok Sadly, this is programming. You can't avoid loops, no way, but you can encapsulate your logic so you can use it everywhere and avoid repeating again and again the same loop.

Answer (score 5):

The [RemoveAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) method with predicate will do if you are using a List

```
public int RemoveAll(
    Predicate<T> match
)
```

> The Predicate(Of T) delegate that defines the conditions of the elements to remove.

```
 List<MyClass > f = new List<MyClass >();
 f.RemoveAll(x => ! ValidateObject(x) );
```

Comment: +1, but I think the goal is to remove objects for which ValidateObject returns false: !ValidateObject(x)

Answer (score 3):

You can't modify a collection while enumerating it.

Try using Linq:

```
var validObjects = Objects.Where(z => ValidateObject(z));
```

Comment: [answer to deleted answer] From what I understand from the OP's question, he wants to remove objects and "don't want to use loop here".
Fine, there is no loop here using Linq. This answers the question.

Comment: I don't think so, Linq do loops too. Ok, `Where` does a loop in a single line, but it's a loop again.

Comment: Your code is confusing because your `obj` variable represents multiple objects. Also your code gets objects which are valid, not invalid, and does not delete them.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: It's an implementation detail hidden for the developer. You'll **always** have to loop through your collection to see if each of its items is valid or not. RemoveAll does the same.

Comment: @Meta-Knight: The result of an enumeration is always an object (even if it's a collection), so obj is OK. Rename it according to the context of your project. I could have write z or i or tmp instead of obj, this is just a sample, I don't know the meaning of the collection.
Anyway, the code returns valid objects, you're right.

Comment: @ken2k: I understand your point of view, but since obj could be anything, and some StackOverflow users might not know about the Where function, I believe choosing a more explicit name for that variable would help understand what it's doing.

Comment: @Meta-Knight OK, you're right, I'll edit the answer and change the variable name.

Comment: @ken2k But, in my opinion, your answer solves nothing about the OP question. Ok, you filter valid objects, but you don't remove invalid ones from the collection.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Actually there are two points of view. The first is, "OP wants to remove invalid objects", and I agree, the code above doesn't answer this question. The second POV is "OP wants to remove invalid objects from its collection so its collection will only contain valid objects". The code above answers this question.

Comment: @ken2k Again, you're not removing nothing in your use case. You're filtering a collection. And any of your both use cases described in your above comments are explaining the same thing, double-check it :D "Remove invalid objects from collection" or "Remove object from collection to have a collection of valid objects only". Maybe I got crazy, but it's the same, isn't it?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I don't think you're crazy, but for me it's not the same at all ;-) In the first use case, the result is "I removed invalid objects from the collection": the main request is to **remove something from a collection**. In the second use case, the result is "Now the collection contains only valid objects": the main request is that **the resulting collection doesn't contain invalid objects anymore**. Here it's not the removal process that is important, but the actual result. Hope my POV in better explained here ;)

Comment: @ken2k Haha, I know you don't think so ;) I knew what use case solves your answer, but I wanted to clarify with you that OP wants to remove objects from a collection in a single line instead of getting a collection of valid objects, discriminating invalid ones. Mainly, OP should be asking "How to get valid objects from a collection contaning invalid ones?" to let your answer be the right one. That's all :D

Answer (score 1):

After all, there's no way a collection which is typed as `IEnumerable<T>`, `ICollection<T>` or so could remove an item based on some criteria.

But you can create an extension method like this:

```
public static void CollectionsExtensions
{
      public static void RemoveInvalidItems(this ICollection<MyClass> some)
      {
             foreach(MyClass item in some.ToList())
             {
                    if(!new Validator().ValidateObject(item)) // Your class having your validation method
                    {
                          some.Remove(item);
                    }
             }
       }
}
```

So, at the end of the day, you can convert your loop to remove invalid objects into:

```
someCollectionOfMyClass.RemoveInvalidItems();
```

Summary: you can remove all invalid items in a single line for any collection implementing `ICollection<MyClass>`, which includes some like:

- `IList<T>`
- `List<T>`
- and more!

Answer (score 0):

Use this to filter out valid objects:

```
var validObjects = Objects.Where(t=>ValidateObject(obj));
```

Comment: I don't find any difference by using Linq or a `for-each` iterator and it does solve nothing.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer - can you explain how it does nothing if it filters the collection and does not use a loop?

Comment: @GarryVass Yeah, you're right, I missed the "single line" thing, but, by the way, do you think your answer solves "remove an object from this collection in a single line"?

Comment: And after all, in any of LINQ suggestions, are you really removing an item of this collection? You're filtering, instead of removing!

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer -> fair observation.

Comment: @GarryVass Any of answers' authors should check that, it's obvious, but any of them answers nothing, these could be a simple question's comment...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer - I have retagged it to make it clearer, hopefully

Comment: @GarryVass I've re-re-tagged "icollection" to "collection", which has questions associated with it :)